# My Calendar generation code is slow. How do I improve it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a model I have created to generate iCal and the necessary JSON for the jQuery calendar plugin [Full Calendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) to work. When I display the page, the JSON generation takes about 7 seconds. The query itself has been running in only a few microseconds. So I know my code is the problem.

I was trying to get the format like what [Full Calendar expects](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) thus why I wrote the code how I did. My guess is that the below is the problem. Any thoughts on where I can improve this?

```
#region Event
public class Event
{
    public string Title { set; get; }
    public string Description { set; get; }
    public string URL { set; get; }
    public string UID { set; get; }
    public DateTime DateTimeStamp { set; get; }
    public DateTime CreatedDateTime { set; get; }
    public DateTime Start { set; get; }
    public DateTime End { set; get; }
    public bool AllDay { set; get; }
}
#endregion

public class Calendar
{
    #region Model
    public string CalendarName { set; get; }
    public string Product { set; get; }
    public string TimeZone { set; get; }
    public List<Event> Events { private set; get; }
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a calendar json string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string ToFullCalendarJsonString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append("[");

        int count = Events.Count;
        int i = 0;

        foreach (Event eventItem in Events)
        {
            sb.Append("{");
            sb.AppendFormat("\"title\":\"{0}\",", eventItem.Title);
            sb.AppendFormat("\"allDay\":\"{0}\",", eventItem.AllDay);

            if (eventItem.AllDay)
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("\"start\":\"{0}T00:00:00\",", eventItem.Start.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                sb.AppendFormat("\"end\":\"{0}T00:00:00\",", eventItem.End.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
            }
            else
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("\"start\":\"{0}T{1}\",", eventItem.Start.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), eventItem.Start.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
                sb.AppendFormat("\"end\":\"{0}T{1}\",", eventItem.End.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), eventItem.End.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
            }
            sb.AppendFormat("\"url\":\"{0}\"", eventItem.URL);
            sb.Append("}");

            i++;

            if (i < count)
            {
                sb.Append(",");
            }
        }

        sb.Append("]");

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: This is for `[asp.net-mvc-2]` but I can't tag it as such.

Comment: How many events do you have?

Comment: About 80 and more as we keep going.

Comment: @Mike, well, sounds very strange. I was testing in console application and I had 5 seconds for about 20,000 events.

Comment: The data comes from an iSeries. I hope that isn't part of the problem.

Comment: @Mike, what is it?

Comment: @Snowbear What is an [iSeries](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/i/)? It is an enterprise level database/application server. A midrange computer.

Comment: @Mike, I didn't know it. And due to some exception in my mind I thought that first google `iseries` results are not related to your `iseries`. Regarding your concern. I thought it was the first thing you've tested - that this exact function is performance bottleneck. Otherwise all our answers won't make any sense.

Comment: The query itself takes 200 ms or so. I got the performance to a couple seconds. For now that is acceptable. I'll have to restructure quite a bit more if I more complaints. For now I am moving on. The software is in beta anyway. When people start to complain and I have more time, then I'll re-factor everything to try and make it faster.

Comment: @Mike Wills: I'm guessing the major speed difference between our tests and your observations indicate another problem. How exactly did you determine that it is the particular code you mention here which is slow? For quick time checks, like those posted in my answer I simply use `Environment.Ticks` before and after the particular code I'm trying to measure, and look at the difference between the two. When more advanced profiling is needed, use a profiler.

Comment: @Steven: I know where another problem lies. I don't have time at this point to fix it. There are 3 or 4 loops in the entire process of generating this. I am going to eliminate a couple of the loops and see if that helps at some point.

Comment: @Mike Wills: It might be worthwhile posting the code of these loops in a new question. ;p

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just [read somewhere](http://www.dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder-1) that `AppendFormat()` can be slower than simple `Append()` calls. Being shocked by reading this, I decided to investigate.

For 1,000,000 empty events the times required are:

- With AppendFormat: **9297** ticks
- Without AppendFormat: **8268** ticks

That is a considerable difference of **11%**!

I'm guessing this is due to the lookup of the arguments and such. It would be nice if `AppendFormat()` would be recompiled to `Append()` calls only by default.

This is the code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a calendar json string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string ToFullCalendarJsonStringFaster()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append( "[" );

        int count = Events.Count;
        int i = 0;

        foreach ( Event eventItem in Events )
        {
            sb.Append( "{" );

            sb.Append("\"title\":\"");
            sb.Append(eventItem.Title);
            sb.Append("\",");
            sb.Append("\"allDay\":\"");
            sb.Append(eventItem.AllDay);
            sb.Append("\",");

            if ( eventItem.AllDay )
            {
                // My test never comes here, so I left it out.
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append("\"start\":\"");
                sb.Append(eventItem.Start.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                sb.Append("T");
                sb.Append(eventItem.Start.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
                sb.Append("\",");

                sb.Append("\"end\":\"");
                sb.Append(eventItem.End.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                sb.Append("T");
                sb.Append(eventItem.End.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
                sb.Append("\",");
            }
            sb.Append("\"url\":\"");
            sb.Append(eventItem.URL);
            sb.Append("\"");
            sb.Append( "}" );

            i++;

            if ( i < count )
            {
                sb.Append( "," );
            }
        }

        sb.Append( "]" );

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

By also applying Snowbear's earlier replies:

- Using `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` as format strings, gives an extra speed difference of **5%**
- Preallocating `StringBuilder` size, gives an extra speed difference of **6%**

In total, after applying all changes, the code is **22%** faster. :)

Bottomline is, there probably isn't a 'magic' solution which can make it go instant with so many events, but you can improve the speed considerably. I suggest you run the processing on a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

---

... this is getting even more ridiculous. Changing the date formatting to the following:

```
//sb.Append(eventItem.Start.ToString( "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss" ) );
sb.Append(eventItem.Start.Year);
sb.Append("-");
sb.Append(eventItem.Start.Month);
sb.Append("-");
sb.Append(eventItem.Start.Day);
sb.Append("T");
sb.Append(eventItem.Start.Hour);
sb.Append(":");
sb.Append(eventItem.Start.Minute);
sb.Append(":");
sb.Append(eventItem.Start.Second);
sb.Append("\",");
```

... gives another speed increase and makes it **34%** faster in total. Might slow down 
again if you need more specific formatting.

---

**Beware**: this last update is probably erronous. I asked [a question about proper usage of PLINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5352491/590790).

I haven't used [Parallel LINQ (PLINQ)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx) yet. But this seemed a nice use for it. After replacing the for by:

```
Events.AsParallel().AsOrdered().ForAll( eventItem =>
{
    ...
} );
```

I get a total speed increase of **43%**, again 9% faster. :) This is on a dual core processor. PC's with more cores should perform better. I don't know how PLINQ works exactly, but I would think it could work even faster if one iteration doesn't need to wait on another. The `StringBuilder` and `i` are exposed as closures. Anyone got any better approaches than `ForAll()`?

Comment: I've also noticed with your last approach that I got some improvement by explicit conversion of  each date component to string before passing it to `Append`. Though I hadn't time to check it or research on it, but it was surprising to me.

Comment: So ... how could we have forgotten PLINQ? Anybody more experience with it? A simple ForAll already results in another 9% speed increase.

Comment: Wow... your work is impressive on this. Thanks! I'll take a look at your suggestions.

Comment: You have to use [Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd384149.aspx) to get the behavior you want.  The specific overload I linked can aggregate over ranges of the result in parallel, and then merges all the results at the end.

Answer (score 6):

Couple of tricks to improve performance (i've got around +10%, not that much though):

1) Preallocate `stringBuilder` size. You can roughly calculate it's total size as `Events.Count * charsPerEvent`
 2) In this line:  `sb.AppendFormat("\"end\":\"{0}T{1}\",", eventItem.End.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), eventItem.End.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));` combine two parameters into 1 using following format string for date: `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`

Also I doubt you will be able to gain performance. Maybe you can workaround it somehow? For example caching the results. Also you may try instead of creating a new string simply write it to response via `HTTPHandler` if Asp.Net MVC still allows to do it easily. Not sure that it will help also.

Answer (score 2):

Note this is off topic (not a codereview solution but an idea of how to solve the performance problem.)

**It's hard for me to believe that this is really the bottleneck**

Are you sure that this is really the bottleneck? You can test it by returning the same constant fake json string.

```
  string fake2000Events = @"{.......}";

  public string ToFullCalendarJsonString()
  {
     return fake2000Events
  }
```

If performance is much better than calculating real data then you may think of caching results.

Comment: It's not off topic IMHO. It's working code, which is being reviewed, in this particular case for performance. I'd even say that's something which could be added in the FAQ.

Comment: Well, when initially creating it I had a small result set. It was showing immediately. Now that there is real data (about 80-85 in the result set) it is now taking 11 seconds. Yes, it went up from yesterday as more data has been added.

Comment: @Mike Wills: only 85? You should use a profiler and see which calls are slowest.

Comment: @Steven Can a profiler be used when getting data from the iSeries?